# Changing Variables in Discrete Calculus

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, summation, finite-differences, discrete-calculus

In discrete calculus one soon meets the $h$-difference operator $$\Delta_h[f(x)] = f(x+h) - f(x)$$
and we often define $\Delta = \Delta_1.$ We can similarly define the [indefinite sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum) $\Delta_h^{-1}$ and set $\Delta^{-1} = \Delta_1^{-1}.$

Most books on discrete calculus only include results for $h=1.$
For example, the above link gives that
$$\Delta^{-1}\sin rx = \frac{-\cos(r[x-\frac{1}{2}])}{2\sin\frac{r}{2}}$$

Through an ugly computation I managed to work out that $$\Delta_h^{-1}[\sin rx] = \frac{-\cos(r[x-\frac{h}{2}])}{2\sin\frac{rh}{2}}$$

What I'd like is a uniform procedure for recovering the "$h$-version" from such results. How could I have derived the second formula from the first? Is there something like the change of variable formula in calculus? Maybe some version of 'dimensional analysis' that tells you where to insert $h$'s? As another example, given that $$\Delta[\log x] = \log(1 + \frac{1}{x})$$ I'd like to be able to see immediately that $$\Delta_h[\log x] = \log(1 + \frac{h}{x})$$

Any help or references would be welcome.

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful, but if $h\in \Bbb N$ one could write$$f(x+h)-f(x)=[f(x+h)-f(x+h-1)]+[f(x+h-1)-f(x)]=\cdots\\=\sum_{n=0}^{h-1}\Delta_1 f(x+h-n)$$

Comment: have you tried defining $\,f_h(x) := f(hx)\,$ and then define $\,g(x) := \Delta_1[f_h(x)]\,$ which gives $\, g(x) = f_h(x+1) - f_h(x) = f(hx+h) - f(hx).\,$ Now $\, \Delta_h[f(x)] = g(x/h).$

Comment: Could you expand on how this would help me see the correct transformation?

Comment: crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/449377/11260

Answer (score 3):

In the context of discrete calculus define the
$h$-difference operator

$$\Delta_h[f(x)] := f(x+h) - f(x). $$

Notice that  $\,\Delta = \Delta_1\,$ where $\,\Delta\,$
is defined as the difference operator

$$ \Delta[f(x)] := f(x+1) - f(x). $$

You asked the question

> What I'd like is a uniform procedure for recovering the "h-version" from such results.

Sadly, the answer, in general, is no.
Consider any function that has period $1$. That is, $\,f(x+1) = f(x)\,$ for all $\,x.\,$
This is equivalent to $\,\Delta[f(x)] = 0.\,$
Thus, all information about the function is lost.
There is no way to compute $\,\Delta_h[f(x)]\,$ from
the $\,\Delta_1\,$ result.

Again, consider any function $\,f(x)\,$ and suppose that the
first difference $\,g(x) := \Delta[f(x)]\,$ is known. Then the
$2$-difference is $\,\Delta_2[f(x)] = f(x+2)-f(x) = g(x)+g(x+1).\,$
now, in general, these is no easy way to express this in terms
of $\,g(x).\,$

This is only a special case of the general problem. Suppose given
any function of two variables $\,f(h,x)\,$ where we only know the
explicit expression for $\,f(1,x).\,$ It is impossible, in general,
to recover the expression for $\,f(h,x).\,$

However, given more information, it may be possible to get results.

For the $h$-difference example, suppose the expression for the function
$$ F_r(x) := \Delta[f(rx)] = f(rx+r) - f(rx) $$
is known. Then
$$ \Delta_h[f(rx)] = f(r(x+h)) - f(rx) = f(rx+rh) - f(rx) = F_{rh}(x/h). $$

For the indefinite sum example, suppose the expression for the function
$$ G_r(x) := \Delta^{-1}[f(rx)] $$
is known where $\,\Delta[G_r(x)] = G_r(x+1) - G_r(x) = f(rx).\,$
Then similarly
$$ \Delta_h^{-1}[f(rx)] = G_{rh}(x/h) $$
because
$$ \Delta_h[G_{rh}(x/h)] = 
G_{rh}\left(\frac{x+h}h\right) - G_{rh}\left(\frac{x}h\right) \\
= G_{rh}\left(\frac{x}h+1\right) - G_{rh}\left(\frac{x}h\right) = f(rx). $$

Comment: I do think this "recovery" becomes possible if you know $\Delta_1[f(rx)]$ for any real $r$ (as in the examples given by the OP); see https://mathoverflow.net/a/449547/11260

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for that comment! I will use my old comment in my answer.

Comment: just for the record: my comment was in response to an earlier version of this answer, without the part starting with "However, given more information, it may be possible to get results."